# PhoneGap and Dreamweaver CS6 Plugin

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

I am having a play with Dreamweaver CS6 and the Phonegap build function

Do you know if it is possible to add Phonegap plugins, as it gets built by DW/Phonegap in CS6 unlike the older version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the future, but I wouldn't count on Adobe updating it for additional features until CS6.5, based on the track experience I have had with mobile apps and Dreamweaver.

No biggie either way - just zip the folder and upload to http://build.phonegap.com - that is essentially what DW is doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find the latest PhoneGap plugin for CS6 Dreamweaver?
It's currently not working properly for some reason (maybe another 24 hours?).
Manually does work but it won't run anymore on Android test device, since Cordova came out of incubation (that doesn't seem right).